# Php preg_match issue not working

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to find a php preg_match that can match:

"2-20 to 2-25"

from this text:

user levels 2-20 to 2-25 not ready

I tried

```
preg_match("/([0-9]+) to ([0-9]+)/", $vars[1] , $matchesto);
```

but the result is:

"20 to 2"

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is almost correct; just include the dashes and adjust the capture group:

```
([-0-9]+ to [-0-9]+)
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/eD6lQ2/1

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `[0-9]+` matches `one or more numbers` but won't match a hyphen (`-`).

Try this:

```
$pattern = '~([0-9]+-[0-9]+) to ([0-9]+-[0-9]+)~Ui';
preg_match($pattern, $vars[1] , $matchesto);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "\d" to match the digits:

```
<?php
$str = 'user levels 2-20 to 2-25 not ready';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/(\d+-\d+) to (\d+-\d+)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "2-20 to 2-25"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "2-20"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "2-25"
}
```